# Spring Boot Microservices RabbitMq org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a problem about listening the message through RabbitListener.

I got this issue on the console.

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [com.springbootmicroservices.advertisement.dto.AdvertisementDto] to [com.springbootmicroservices.report.dto.AdvertisementDto] for GenericMessage [payload=AdvertisementDto(id=1, title=Advertisement 1 for User 1, viewCount=1), headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=queue-advertisement, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=queue-advertisement, amqp_redelivered=false, id=ee288162-ac5a-749b-eddb-3724b0b05755, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-lMN6cQgBhDXZlME7_J_RFQ, amqp_lastInBatch=false, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, timestamp=1659275716934}]
```

How can I fix the issue.

Here is my message service of report service shown below.

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${queue.name}")
@Override
public void receiveMessage(@Payload AdvertisementDto advertisementDto) {
    
   LOGGER.info("MessageServiceImpl | receiveMessage is started");
    
   LOGGER.info("MessageServiceImpl | receiveMessage | Report is creating");
    
   reportService.createReport(advertisementDto);
}
```

Here is my project link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices)

Here is the screenshots : [Image Link 1](https://ibb.co/6ndsV3x)
[Image Link 2](https://ibb.co/p00bBn7)

Here is AdvertisementDto of Advertisement Service

```
@Data
public class AdvertisementDto implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Long viewCount;
}
```

Here is AdvertisementDto of Report Service

```
@Data
public class AdvertisementDto implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Long viewCount;
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than one class called `AdvertisementDto` in your project, in different packages? One in `com.springbootmicroservices.advertisement.dto` and another one in `com.springbootmicroservices.report.dto`?

Comment: @andrewJames I editted my post.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was not clear. I was not suggesting any changes/fixes. I was only asking about the class names. You can certainly do that (duplicate class names in different packages), but it can be confusing and it may lead to errors. I don't know if it's relevant to your specific problem.

Comment: @andrewJames I tried to find this way adding advertisement dependency into report service. But I cannot run docker-compose.

Comment: @andrewJames I still cannot fix the issue.